# How to return colour of point in scatterplot Python

Tags: python, matplotlib

Is there a way to obtain the colour (or a simple yes/no answer if colour is present) from the x, y coordinates of a matplotlib scatterplot?

Basically I want to give a coordinate (x, y) and know if there is a coloured circle at that position in my plot.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

To determine if there is a scatter circle at a position `(xi,yi)` is not straight forward. The problem is that `(xi,yi)` are given in data coordinates, while the circle is drawn as a circle in display coordinates. This means that the circle in display coordinates might acutally be an ellipse in data coordinates, when the axis scaling is different for x and y axis.

Matplotlib contains some functionality to determine if a point given in display coordinates is within the extent of an artist. I order to use this, the canvas first has to be drawn. One might then simulate a mouse event at the position `(xi,yi)` and detect if it hits any artist from the scatter. The respective color can then be retrieved.

```
import numpy as np; np.random.seed(0)
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.backend_bases

x = np.random.rayleigh(size=10)
y = np.random.normal(size=10)
c = np.random.rand(10)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
sc = ax.scatter(x,y,c=c, s=49, picker=True)

fig.canvas.draw()

def color_at_pos(xi,yi):
    xi, yi = ax.transData.transform((xi,yi))
    me = matplotlib.backend_bases.LocationEvent("no", fig.canvas, xi, yi)
    cont, ind = sc.contains(me)
    return sc.cmap(sc.norm(sc.get_array()[ind["ind"]]))

col = color_at_pos(1.25931,0.145889)
print col
col = color_at_pos(0.7,0.7)
print col

plt.show()
```

Here the first point `(1.25931,0.145889)` is actuall within two circles, so two colors are printed, while the second point is not in any circle and an empty array is printed.

Comment: Thank you so much. this is what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

You can use get_color() e.g.

```
a = plt.plot(x,c, color="blue", linewidth=2.0, linestyle="-")
b = plt.plot(x,s, color="red", linewidth=2.0, linestyle="-")

print a[0].get_color()
print b[0].get_color()

>>blue
>>red
```

Or you could assign the returned colors to variables to work with:

```
color_a = a[0].get_color()

if color_a == 'blue':
    ..do something
```

Comment: I doubt that this is what's meant in the question.

Comment: Ok, I will delete it that turns out to be the case.